# Ruby on Rails search method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I want to my user to be able to search by title and description so I have added this line of code.
Here is the error i receive

> wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: title LIKE ? or
>   description LIKE ?

```
 def index

    @posts = Post.where(["title LIKE ? or description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"]).page(params[:page]).per(10)

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using two `?` in this statement. so, the interpreter is expecting 2 arguments for each `?`.
change your code to this:

```
@posts = Post.where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%").page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can name your arguments when you use the hash syntax - for example name it just `:q`:

```
@posts = Post
  .where('title LIKE :q or description LIKE :q', q: "%#{params[:search]}%")
  .page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to check Case insensitive matching

```
 @posts = Post.where("LOWER(title) LIKE ? OR LOWER(description) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search].downcase}%", "%#{params[:search].downcase}%").page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this gem called [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack). Although is focused on forms, you can still make great simple search queries. See this documentation: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching